# Meaning of "à présent" in this André Gide passage

Tags: sens, syntaxe

The question is on the highlighted sentence in this passage from La porte étroite by André Gide.

> Sans doute imaginez-vous aisément avec quels transports de joie je lus cette lettre, et avec quels sanglots d’amour. D’autres lettres suivirent. Certes Alissa me remerciait de ne point venir à Fongueusemare, certes elle m’avait supplié de ne point chercher à la revoir cette année, mais elle regrettait mon absence, **elle me souhaitait à présent** ; de page en page retentissait le même appel. Où pris-je la force d’y résister ? Sans doute dans les conseils d’Abel, dans la crainte de ruiner tout à coup ma joie et dans un raidissement naturel contre l’entraînement de mon cœur.

**QUESTION**

How should I parse it?  Is it one of the following?  If not, what?

1. *à présent* simply means *now* and qualifies *souhaitait*. Thus *her hoping for me* is taking place *now*.
2. *présent* means *presence* as opposed to *absence*. Thus, it is somehow part of what she hopes, for example, she hopes for *my being present*.

**BACKGROUND**

Translations didn't help.

Felix Paul Greve seems to have taken parsing 1 above:

> ... aber es tat ihr leid, daß ich nicht da war, sie sehnte sich **jetzt** nach mir; von Seite zu Seite hallte derselbe Ruf.

Maria Honeit, parsing 2:

> ... aber sie bedauerte, daß ich nicht da war, es verlangte sie nach meiner **Gegenwart**, auf jeder Seite spürte man diesen Ruf.

Dorothy Bussy dismisses *à présent*:

> ... but she regretted my absence, she wanted me; from page to page there sounded the same appeal.

As an aside, it seems all three translations are cranking up *souhaiter* to something more definite or desperate.

Unrelated: This [earlier question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23386/sequence-of-tense-involving-imperfect-and-simple-past) of mine is still (essentially) unanswered.  I would be very grateful if someone took a crack at it.

Comment: Please, edit your question, and provide translations if you use a 3rd language, like German, because most of the people here speak at least French and English, but with additionnal languages, not everyone can read your question.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE But that's why the quotes are relegated to a BACKGROUND section.  They are not part of the question (don't need to be read to answer the question). And the whole point of the translations is to show how other people have interpreted the original passage (here, to show that they too seem to have had trouble with it). But if I were to translate the translations, then the result would no longer be Greve's or Honeit's interpretation. If anyone simply wanted to know what those 3rd language passages said, why, they would translate back into Gide's original.

Comment: On lira avec intérêt l'entrée pour [_présent_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A9sent/1) (voir I.C. loc. adv.), au TLFi...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gide really means "now", insisting on the difference with her past attitude.